# Django: Message appears twice

Tags: django

Anyone understands why my message always appears twice? `print("Test")` only appears once in the console which adds more to my confusion. In my base.html I implement the message framework through `{% include "snippets/messages.html" %}`

[image]

```
@login_required
def claim(request, organizer, event):
    context = {}
    user = request.user
    selected_event = get_object_or_404(Event, slug=event, organizer__slug=organizer)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ClaimRewardForm(
            request.POST,
            initial={
                'event': selected_event,
                'user': user,
            },
        )
        if form.is_valid():
            new_reward_transaction = form.save(commit=False)
            new_reward_transaction.amount_paid = form.cleaned_data['reward'].price
            new_reward_transaction.ambassador = user.ambassador_profile
            new_reward_transaction.reward = form.cleaned_data['reward']
            new_reward_transaction.save()

            # Add success message
            messages.add_message(
                request,
                messages.SUCCESS,
                _("Your reward claim was send for approval. You will receive a final confirmation via email.")
            )
            print("TEST")
            return redirect(
                'ambassadors:event',
                organizer=organizer,
                event=event,
            )
    else:
        # TODO Marc: How to avoid repeating myself
        form = ClaimRewardForm(
            initial={
                'event': selected_event,
                'user': request.user,
            },
        )

    # NEXT: Check if there is any reward that can be claimed

    return render(request, 'ambassadors/claim.html', {
        'context': context,
        'form': form,
    })
```

base.html

```
  <body>

        {% include "partials/header.html" %}

        {% include "snippets/messages.html" %}

        {% block content_before %}
        {% endblock %}

        <main role="main" class="container py-5">
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock %}
        </main>
```

Comment: What's in `partials/header.html` and `snippets/messages.html`?

Comment: Your message tag is included in 2 templates extending each other. are you sure that `{% include "partials/header.html" %}` doesn't have the message tag as well? can you show us partials/header.html template?

Comment: Ahh awesome thank you! That was the issue. header also included the message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your message tag is included in 2 templates extending each other. are you sure that {% include "partials/header.html" %} doesn't have the message tag as well?